# How to locate empty (f.i. white) space in a picture fast

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing

What is the `fastest & most efficient way` to locate empty (white) space in a `System.Drawing.Image`? (There is no need to say to use `LockBits` and `unsafe`...)

My task is to find the location to `place a rectangualr image into an existing image` by not covering up the existing content...
In my case the existing image is a rendered image out of an pdf document.

**My goal is to place another image at the bottommost possible position where there is enough space:** 
(the green one in the following example)
[image: Text as Image with white space]

- Would it be a good decission to scan every pixel and find the right location?
- Or is there a more efficient way? Maybe to use a Grid and look for a summary value to evaluate small areas?

Maybe someone knows an existing & fast algorithm or can provide an example code?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your example the whole with of the document is white where you want to put your image. Is this always the case or may you need to place the image right or left to a text too?

Comment: I expect that there could be content at the left side too... 1rst possible place from buttom to top and right to left ("like a signature")

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid to scan most pixels by trying to eliminate large areas with few pixel tests.

Let the width of the picture be **WIDTH**.
Let the height of the picture be **HEIGHT**.

You can tile the document in tiles of size **WIDTH/2+1** by **HEIGHT/2+1** pixels.

Wherever it is possible to place the picture, it will cover exactly one of these tiles completely.

Therefore my algorithm would be something like this:

1. Create a 2D array (or similar data-structure) of Boolean as a marker for each tile it is completely within.
2. Loop over all the tiles.
3. For each tile check pixels until you either hit a non white pixel (mark the tile as not white) or you have scanned all pixels (mark the tile as *white*). To scan the pixels of a tile I would use an interlace pattern like `png` uses in interlace mode. This way you most likely get lucky an find a non white pixel with testing far less than all pixels of the tile.
4. Check for each white tile (starting form bottom left to top right) if it can be expanded to the size of the picture. (Use again an interlace pattern to minimize number of compares)